# How to prove that $(C( F), \langle.,.\rangle_2)$ is a pre-Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products

Let $F$ be a surface. For all continuous functions $f,g \in C(F) $ define
$$ \langle f,g\rangle_2 := \int_F f(x)g(x)\, dx $$

I'm struggling to show, that $ (C(F),\langle.,.\rangle_2) $ is a pre-hilbert space. Can you help me out? :) Any help will be very appreciated.

Showing that $<f,g>$ is a scalarproduct:

1.

$ 0 \leq $   $<f,f> $
and if $ <f,f>=0 $
$ \leftrightarrow  \int_F f(x)f(x) do(x)=0 $

then $f(x) =0 $

2.
$<f+h,g>= \int_F (f+h)(x)g(x) do(x) = \int_F f(x)g(x)+\int_f h(x)g(x)= \int_F f(x)g(x) do(x) + \int h(x)g(x) do(x)= <f,g>+<h,g> $

3.
$ < \lambda f,g>= \lambda <f,g> $ is clear

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: do I ''only'' have to show, that $<f,g>$ is a scalarproduct?

Comment: Yes. I guess the base field is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @wondering1123 yes, you need to show that $\langle.,.\rangle_2$ is an inner product

Comment: thanks! I edited some more.

Comment: ah forget.. You are not talking about the completion..